# T-SQL determine specific character

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In my table, I got the data `98753201_en_GB.dwg`. I want to determine the position of the dot `.` and I want to the 6 characters just before that - here: `_en_GB`.

It must be variable, so I cannot just use substring. Any ideas?

Comment: Look up TSQL's string functions: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984(v=sql.105).aspx. Find the function that gives you the position of a substring ('.' in your case). Then use `SUBSTRING` with the help of found position.

Comment: Whats @ThorstenKettner probably means is that while you can easily find the answer here or any other place in Internet (in fact he could have given you the answer in less time than it took to write his comment), it is actually better for you to realise that doing some work yourself will benefit you more in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

You have misplaced your parentheses:

```
declare @test varchar(50);
set @test = '37 21_98753201_en_GB.dwg';
select substring(@test, charindex('.', @test) - 6, 6);
```

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thx

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
;WITH cte_TestData(FileNames) AS
(
SELECT '37 21_98753201_en_GB.dwg' UNION ALL
SELECT '38 21_98753203_en_GB.dwg' UNION ALL
SELECT '39 21_98753204_en_GB.dwg' UNION ALL
SELECT '40 21_98753205_en_GB.dwg' UNION ALL
SELECT '41 21_98753206_en_GB.dwg'
)
SELECT SUBSTRING([FileNames], CHARINDEX('.',[FileNames])-6, 6) 
FROM cte_TestData
```

---

In case left part of the string has a period, the below code can also be used

```
;WITH cte_TestData(FileNames) AS
(
SELECT '37 21_98753201_en_GB.dwg' UNION ALL
SELECT '38 21_98753203_en_GB.dwg' UNION ALL
SELECT '39 21_98753204_en_GB.dwg' UNION ALL
SELECT '40.21_98753205_en_GB.dwg' UNION ALL
SELECT '41.21_98753206_en_GB.dwg'
)
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([FileNames]),CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE([FileNames])) + 1,LEN(REVERSE([FileNames]))),1,6))
FROM cte_TestData
```

Comment: I am sure you read my answer before posting yours... What part of it you didn't like?

Comment: The query is in response to niklas's comment where he has the bracket in the wrong place. Did you see that comment @GiorgosAltanis?

Comment: As a matter of fact I read it, commented on it, and answered the question several minutes before your actions... That's why I ask you, is it anything wrong with my answer?

Comment: Noting wrong with your code, just ran it and works fine but I am still not sure what this conversation is all about? i am going through my comments and I do not think I ever commented anything about your code so little lost here mate?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's probably right, but I'm very new to TSQL.

What I got now: SUBSTRING([FileName],CHARINDEX('.',[FileName]-6),6).

I get the error: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '37 21_98753201_en_GB.dwg' to data type int.

Comment: Please edit your question to include this "What I got now" part - this will improve its quality and prevent downvotes. You can read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well.

Comment: You have the bracket in the wrong place try this SUBSTRING([FileName],CHARINDEX('.',[FileName])-6,6)